# Ubuntu 14.04 32 bit getting "Kernel panic - not syncing" when trying to install on VMware player

Tags: 14.04, virtualization, vmware-player

I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 on my work computer. First i had to active VT in bios and now I get this error and cant fix it:

[image: http://puu.sh/ckzZe/fd68cf9bde.png]

The computer uses i3-4130 CPU with 8GB of brand new RAM.

I already tried setting the processor to Intel VT-x or AMD-v in the Virtualization engine option but i got the same error

Comment: Does it hang forever after that? What version of ubuntu?

Comment: yea it hangs forever i need to reboot the VMware window and as i wrote its 14.04 i also tested it with 12 and its the same problem.

Comment: You just wrote 14. Thanks for clarifying. What is the host OS? And have you set it up to be booting Ubuntu specifically?

Comment: Host is windows 7 and yes its set up to boot linux. I also tryed difrent methods like not choosing OS option and then later emulating the iso in the virtual drive and booting it up which also results in the same error also i tested both the 32 and 64 versions of 14.04 and 12 and both come to the same thing

Comment: Is there an option to be specifically Ubuntu, not linux?

Comment: Oh i am sorry yes there is ubuntu option which is the one i used both ubuntu and ubuntu 64 which i used for the corresponding iso

Comment: Okay. From what you have said, it sounds like a problem with the host because it is affecting 32 and 64 and 14.04 and 12.04. Maybe try asking on http://superuser.com

Comment: Are the kvm modules loaded at this time?  Do you have anything else like virtualbox also installed? Make sure those modules are unloaded and try again. It "shouldn't" be a problem, but sometimes it is.

Comment: Is it set to LiveCd (there are checkmarks in both VMware and VirtualBox for this option), and is the iso a liveboot image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the fix was rather simple, the new work computer i got had vmware player preinstalled and ofcourse i though it was the latest version, as it turned out it was not, so i updated it and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

What guest os option did you set in vmware for the ubuntu? If you set to a specific guest os option in vmware, please try selecting "Other"

Changing guest os option is best to format the guest again to see if the new option setting works for you.

Please try because such panics are common in virtualization partially due to wrong guest option to ISO / OS type. Happens in Virtualbox and Xen for me.

Comment: Had a similar problem, solved by changing the guest OS to Windows NT.